# accessing variables in loaded source while in irb

Tags: ruby, irb

Say I have a file named test1.rb with the following code:

```
my_array = [1, 2, 3, 4 5]
```

Then I run irb and get an irb prompt and run "require 'test1'. At this point I am expecting to be able to access my_array. But if I try to do something like...

```
puts my_array
```

irb tells me "my_array" is undefined. Is there a way to access "my_array"

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2699324/ruby-irb-requires-and-scope

Answer (score 9, accepted):

like this:

```
def my_array
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
end
```

Comment: Note, if you are doing something more complicated than creating an array, you may want to setup a local instance variable to hold the resulting object... such as my "load" initializes a connection to an API for testing, with the credentials and everything., so after my "load" I just do api = my_api

Answer (score 4):

You can also require your script and access that data in a few other ways.  A local variable cannot be accessed, but these other three data types can be accessed within the scope, similar to the method definition.

```
MY_ARRAY = [1, 2, 3, 4 5] #constant
@my_array = [1, 2, 3, 4 5] #instance variable
@@my_array = [1, 2, 3, 4 5] #class variable
def my_array # method definition
  [1, 2, 3, 4 5]
end
```

Answer (score 1):

No, there isn't. Local variables are always local to the scope they are defined in. That's why they are called *local variables*, after all.

Answer (score 1):

In irb:

```
  eval(File.read('myarray.rb'),binding)
```

Or you could [drop to irb](http://errtheblog.com/posts/9-drop-to-irb)

Comment: i was really hoping this would work but i still get "undefined local variable" error

Comment: can you show the exact code you tested with, or maybe a dump of the session, because this does work.

Comment: in a file called "myarray.rb" i have "my_array = (1..5).to_a". then in irb i do eval(File.read('myarray.rb')) which outputs "[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]". That is good but i want to then be able to access "my_array" but it doesn't exist in the current session of irb.

Comment: oh, sorry, you need to pass a binding to eval:
    eval(File.read('myarray.rb'), binding)

Answer (score 0):

Defining in your file

```
@my_array = [1, 2, 3, 4 5]
```

then calling it in your IRB, after loading and requiring

```
@my_array
```

Will work