# How to run a .rb file from IRB?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, irb, osx-leopard

I am starting out with Ruby on Rails. I am currently going through a tutorial that says that I have to run a .rb file from IRB to create a .xml file in my current directory.

My question is how do I run a .rb file in IRB?

I tried the following: just typing `irb` on the command line in the directory of the file. That starts an IRB session as far as I understand.
Then I typed

```
irb filename.rb
```

which went through, but didn't create anything in the current directory.

Answer (score 185):

You can "run" a file in irb by just requiring or loading it.

```
$ irb
>> load './filename.rb'
```

To change your current working directory within irb, you can use *FileUtils*:

```
>> require 'fileutils'
>> FileUtils.pwd # prints working directory
>> FileUtils.cd '/path/to/somewhere' # changes the directory
```

Comment: to require it from irb you need to provide the fully qualified path, thus: 

`require '~/myrubystuff/coolstuff.rb'`  

instead of just 

`require 'coolstuff'`

Comment: I was able to require `fileutils` by name alone, no directory path needed. I'm sure it's environment dependent and not everyone will need to use the qualified path.

Comment: note local variables aren't available automatically, although there are easy workarounds https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2699324/how-can-i-access-a-variable-defined-in-a-ruby-file-i-required-in-irb

Answer (score 9):

In case you want to have your file loaded in the **irb** session and you are using Ruby 2+ you can load a file in **irb** like this:

```
irb -r ./the_name_of_your_file.rb
```

This opens an irb session with the given file loaded.

Imagine you have file with a class like this:

```
class Example
  def initialize(name)
    @name = name
  end

  def print__example
    p name
  end
end
```

You will be able to use the Example class in the **irb** session.

Comment: that was what i was actually searching for, thanks a lot!

Comment: This gives access only to functions, not variables defined in the file.

Answer (score 3):

We can just create a .rb file in the directory which you are currently working in using any text editor and type all the code in that and then use the command `ruby filename.rb` in the terminal, not in the irb, then it shows the output in irb.

Comment: But by loading the file you can access variables defined there. Handy when troubleshooting or playing with a library.

Comment: @Sreenivas This was just what I was looking for. Thanks!