# Why does '=> nil' appear in the output when I use this website to code but not when I use Sublime Text?

Tags: ruby, null, sublimetext

I'm a beginner studying Ruby and I noticed that when I use this website (https://repl.it/) to code, '=> nil' sometimes appears in the output. However, when I use Sublime Text to code, it does not appear at all.

1) Is it important for it to appear in the output? If so, why?

2) How can I make it so that it does appear in Sublime Text?

Thanks!

Comment: You don't want it to appear in Sublime Text, that would make all of your Ruby invalid.

Comment: `nil` is the return value in the last statement of the script. You can get the same result when running your own `.rb` scripts from the terminal. If you use `ruby file_name.rb` it's only going to output everything you write to stdout and stderr (for example `puts` statements). But if you run it from within *irb* and use `load 'file_name.rb'` you're also going to get the return value of the script as well. See: https://stackoverflow.com/q/6149850/3982562

Answer (score 2, accepted):

nil in this case is just the return value of your method call. It didn't return anything. The repl prints it out for you, but when you run a Ruby file, you won't see it.

e.g. in pry, irb, repl.it, etc.

```
puts 5
```

prints

```
5
=> nil
```

The puts command prints 5, then returns nil. The repl prints that for you, so you know what the return value was. You can try it for yourself

```
def test
  puts 'test'
  return 5
end
test
```

prints

```
test
=> 5
```

If you want it to appear when running a file, you can print the return of the function. e.g.

```
puts "=> #{test.inspect}"
```

result

```
test
=> 5
=> nil # this line only if running in repl
```

Comment: string interpolation of `nil` would be "" so this line `puts "=> #{tes}"` would output `=> ` if `test` returned `nil` you could use `inspect` e.g. `puts "=> #{nil.inspect}"` will output `=> nil`