# How can I create ruby file from irb?

Tags: ruby, irb

I am at the very beginning of learning Ruby. Following the instructions of the assignment I am working on, I need to create a ruby file variables.rb. I wonder if there is a way to do that from the level of irb?

I know that I can do that easily from the level of the terminal via:

touch variables.rb.

Is there a way to do it from the level of irb?

Comment: Compare https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6149850/how-to-run-a-rb-file-from-irb

Comment: But my question would be: why? Just open another terminal window and do it from the shell, or do it with a text editor app. File manipulation in ruby itself is advanced stuff.

Comment: You can suspend irb via Ctrl-Z, create the file via `touch ...`, and run `fg` to resume irb.

Comment: @matt - it seemed like an important possible time optimization considering that I will be running ruby files form irb, and creating files seems like something that happens quite often. At the beginning of the learning process is quite difficult to understand what is really important. Back to the basic stuff now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `File` class

```
File.new("variables.rb", "w")
```

or you can run the same `touch` command in `irb`

```
`touch variables.rb`
```

Comment: I tried both and none of them works. When I write touch foo.txt I get: 2.2.3 :001 > touch  foo.txt
NameError: undefined local variable or method `foo' for main:Object
 from (irb):1
 from /Users/Aleksandra/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/bin/irb:11:in `<main>'

Comment: I tried both and both work :) For the second one you need the two ` for real. It's the way ruby knows to run that in a subshell

Comment: Note that `File.new(...)` returns the opened file object. Pass an empty block to have it closed afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

This will do the trick:

```
File.open("newfilename", "w") { |file| file.puts "your text" }
```

You can also use .write or .print, if you don't want the line break