# Error when opening Ruby File (Beginner) + How to run a file?

Tags: ruby, variables

When I try to open A ruby file in the same directory something weird happens,
like so :

`C:\RubyFiles>file = File.open("Lottery.rb", "r") 
'file' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

now I know this has nothing to do with the opening of the file itself, but I wanted to have an example ;)

(This has been resolved^) :D

But now I would like to know how to run the file itself? Can anyone help? Thanks in advance!

Comment: It has to do with conflating ruby code with your shell. Try running `file = File.open("Lottery.rb", "r") ` after running ruby.exe and seeing where you get to

Comment: you need to go into irb first.

Comment: see here: https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/documentation/quickstart/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After opening irb, you can execute a ruby file using [`Kernel#load`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Kernel.html#method-i-load)

```
load 'Lottery.rb'
```

If this file just includes module/class definitions, you probably only want to load it once. This is what [`Kernel#require`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Kernel.html#method-i-require) ensures:

```
require 'Lottery.rb'
```

Comment: Why can't I used the variables that are in the file to make operations outside of the methods I've already defined(in the file)? I'm trying to return parts of a method, to see if the data was processed the way I want it to.

Comment: Variables declared inside files are not accessible outside the scope of that file. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2699324/ruby-irb-requires-and-scope