# Declaring variables in .rb file result unwanted output

Tags: ruby, irb

I am following [chapter 2 of Understanding Computation](http://cdn.oreillystatic.com/oreilly/booksamplers/9781449329273_sampler.pdf) to build a simple Ruby interpreter:

At some point after Class `Assign`, `Variable` and `Number` are defined (which I think is actually irrelevant), I do this in **irb**

> irb(main):001:0> statement = Assign.new(:x, Add.new(Variable.new(:x), Number.new(1)))

`=> <<x = x + 1>>`

> irb(main):002:0> environment = { x: Number.new(2) }

`=> {:x=><<2>>}`

> irb(main):003:0> statement, environment = statement.reduce(environment)

`=> [<<x = 2 + 1>>, {:x=><<2>>}]`

and everything goes perfectly.

But when I declare `statement` and `environment` in `.rb` file:

```
def statement
    Assign.new(:x, Add.new(Variable.new(:x), Number.new(1)))
end

def environment
    { x: Number.new(2) }
end
```

something goes wrong when I type `statement, environment = statement.reduce(environment)` in **irb**:

> irb(main):001:0> statement, environment = statement.reduce(environment)
>
> NoMethodError: undefined method `reduce` for nil:NilClass
>       from (irb):1
>       from /usr/bin/irb:12:in `<main>`

I don't know if the bug is on the way I declare `statement` or `environment`?

How could I declare the variable in `.rb` file?

I check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2699324/how-can-i-access-a-variable-defined-in-a-ruby-file-i-required-in-irb) and `@variable_name` doesn't seems to work with a non-string variable.

Comment: Looking at the code that you've shown it looks to me like you might have a scoping problem.  Are you doing anything with the return from Assign.new that will allow `environment` to see it or do you simply allow it to go out f scope?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two pieces of code are completely different. The first uses variables, the second uses methods.

Variables are defined like this:

```
name_of_var = initialization_expression
```

Methods are defined like this:

```
def name_of_method(parameter_one, parameter_two)
  body_expression
end
```

> I don't know if the bug is on the way I declare `statement` or `environment`

Yes.

This is what happens:

```
def statement
  Assign.new(:x, Add.new(Variable.new(:x), Number.new(1)))
end

def environment
  { x: Number.new(2) }
end
```

Here you define two methods, `statement` and `environment`. What they do is actually irrelevant because you never call them.

```
statement, environment = statement.reduce(environment)
```

Here, you declare two variables, `statement` and `environment`. You initialize them by calling `reduce` on the contents of the variable `statement` (which is `nil`, because `statement` hasn't been initialized yet (we are just in the process of initializing it, after all) and un-iintialized variables evaluate to `nil` in Ruby) passing as an argument the contents of the variable `environment` (which is also `nil` for the same reason).

You never call the methods you defined, because they are being shadowed by the two variables you created with the same names.

> how could I solve it?

You already did: the first piece of code works.